# Genre of music like Infected Mushroom and Snail's House

Tags: identify-this-genre

Here is a link to some music I listen to (On youtube music). What genre is it?

- [Infected Mushroom - playlist](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=ikjku2OrE6M&feature=share)
- [Snail's House - Pixel Galaxy](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=RK8e4JQgPfo&feature=share)
- [ODESZA - A Moment Apart](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=BwmzXTjDt7A&feature=share)

Are they all the same genre or are they different? Please tell me the genre of each specific one!

Comment: 1. EDM / Dubstep
2. Anime
3. Indie Dance/Pop and EDM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all different subgenres of [pop electronica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronica), a genre based around electronic instruments and drums (where the electronic quality of the sound is highlighted rather than disguised). I'm not an expert on electronica subgenres, but to me these sound like:

1. [EDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_dance_music) - A percussive form of electronic music played mostly at dance clubs.
2. [Chiptune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiptune) - an genre inspired by old videogames that utilizes instruments that sound like very old computers or video game consoles.
3. [Ambient pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_pop) - A style that combines pop music structures and styles with dreamy, atmospheric, electronic sounds.

Answer (score 3):

Infected Mushroom is merging two genres there: [Full-On Psytrance](https://music.ishkur.com/?query=FullOn) and [Chiptune](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/Chiptune/).

Snail's House is the typical case of [Future Bass](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/Future+Bass/) with [J-Pop](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/J-Pop/) influences. Sometimes it's also called Kawaii Future Bass.

ODESZA is also making Future Bass songs (in [Bloom](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=fBMF1SOipck&list=RDAMVMBwmzXTjDt7A)), but in that specific case I think [Electropop](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/Electropop/) with [Chamber Pop](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/Chamber+Pop/) elements is more appropriate.

Sources: https://music.ishkur.com/ https://rateyourmusic.com/